# Endless RecyclerView with Asynctask using EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have an activity which searches for a query (using `async` task and server side `PHP`) and gives out a list in `recycler view`, Now i want to implement **endless/infinite scrolling** when user reaches bottom. I have tried to do that using [`EndlessScrollListener`](https://gist.github.com/zfdang/38ae655a4fc401c99789#file-endlessrecycleronscrolllistener-java). There are two problems i need help with.

first, the new list recreates itself instead of appending to the old list.

second, the `current_page` int variable keeps its value from the previous search and scroll, means when running `AsyncTask` for second time, the `current_page` int variable still retains the value from the first time and does not reset.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVFish;
private AdapterFish mAdapter;
private  LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private String searchQuery;


SearchView searchView = null;


private String query;


private EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener mScrollListener = null;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mRVFish = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mRVFish.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // adds item to action bar
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_main, menu);

    // Get Search item from action bar and Get Search service
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



// Every time when you press search button on keypad an Activity is recreated which in turn calls this function
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Get search query and create object of class AsyncFetch
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }
       int startrow =0;
        String type="";
        String filetype="";

        AsyncFetch myTask = new AsyncFetch(query, startrow,  type,  filetype);


        myTask.execute();



        mScrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

                int startrow=current_page;
                String type="";
                String filetype="";
                AsyncFetch myTask = new AsyncFetch(query, startrow,  type,  filetype);

                myTask.execute();


            }
        };

        mRVFish.addOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);

        // enable pull down to refresh
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                int startrow =0;
                String type="";
                String filetype="";

                AsyncFetch myTask = new AsyncFetch(query, startrow,  type,  filetype);

                myTask.execute();

                // after refresh is done, remember to call the following code
                if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null && mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);  // This hides the spinner
                }
            }
        });



    }

}


// Create class AsyncFetch
private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;
    String searchQuery;
    int startrow;
    String type;
    String filetype;


    public AsyncFetch(String searchQuery,  int startrow, String type, String filetype){
        this.searchQuery=searchQuery;
        this.startrow = startrow;
        this.type = type;
        this.filetype=filetype;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://someurl/json/search.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery).appendQueryParameter("startrow", String.valueOf(startrow));
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {
                return("Connection error");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        List<DataFish> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("no rows")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Results found for entered query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    DataFish fishData = new DataFish();
                    try {
                        fishData.fileName = URLDecoder.decode(json_data.getString("file"), "UTF-8");
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        fishData.fileName=json_data.getString("file");


                    }

                    fishData.linkName = json_data.getString("link");
                    fishData.reg_date = json_data.getString("reg_date");
                    fishData.fileSize = json_data.getString("filesize");
                    data.add(fishData);
                }

                mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);

                   mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);


                if(jArray.length()>19)
                mScrollListener.setLoading(false);
                else
                    mScrollListener.setLoading(true);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }





        }


    }




 }



}
```

EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends 
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private boolean loading = false; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private int visibleThreshold = 0; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

private int current_page = 20;

private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView mRVFish, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(mRVFish, dx, dy);

    if(dy < 0) {
        return;
    }
    // check for scroll down only
    visibleItemCount = mRVFish.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    // to make sure only one onLoadMore is triggered
    synchronized (this) {
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached, Do something


            current_page=current_page+20;
            onLoadMore(current_page);
            loading = true;
        }
    }
}


public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
    this.loading = loading;
}

public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first, the new list recreates itself instead of appending to the old list.

If you set a new adapter you swap the content of the recycler view. I think you do it in the following code

```
mAdapter = new AdapterFish(MainActivity.this, data);
mRVFish.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

To append the data you need to add new elements to the adapter's dataset (dataset where you get data to bind views in your adapter) and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or better `adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)`
There are also a number of tools to optimize adding the elements, like [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html)

> second, the current_page int variable keeps its value from the previous search and scroll, means when running AsyncTask for second time

Not sure what was library developer's idea here, but the easiest way would be to just create a method in the `EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener` similar to:

```
public void resetPage() {
    current_page = 20;
}
```

And call it before invoking new search.

Comment: First problem is fixed, thanks to you.  I'm unable to solve `current_page` problem. can you show me how i can do it?

Comment: It's hard to say, first thing I would suggest you to do is remove the old listener with `removeOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener)` before you create a new one and do `mRVFish.addOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);`